# asp.net vb not working delete in datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

i have datagrid and delete button 
in web application
but dont working this btton 
this is fragment datagrid

```
asp:DataGrid  OnItemCommand="Click_Grid"
runat="server" 
Columns  <asp:ButtonColumn
HeaderText="Silmek Ucun Linke Toxunun"
ButtonType="LinkButton"
Text="Sil"
CommandName="cmdRemoveItem"
Columns
asp:DataGrid
```

and

```
Protected Sub Click_Grid(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As DataGridCommandEventArgs)
Dim DBConn As SqlConnection
Dim DBDelete As New SqlCommand
Dim DBCommand As SqlDataAdapter
Dim DSPageData As New DataSet
DBConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\HP\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\emagazin\emagazin\App_Data\emagaza.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
DBDelete.CommandText = "Delete from ShoppingCartItems " _
    & "Where ShoppingCartItemID = " _& E.Item.Cells(4).Text
```

Comment: where this my error ?

Comment: Yeah... where is it?

Comment: this script from book greg buczek but where is my error i dont was understnd

Comment: Are you sure you will get ShoppingCartItemID in cell 4. Please debug and make sure you will get correct id for delete.